# This data does look correlated right?

Tags: statistics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVK9p.png)

Hey, this data does look correlated correct? Pearson value says the correlation is only .2; I assume the value is this low because the correlation is not linear. Thanks.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you are measuring correlation.  Have you tried using the Spearman coefficient?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistics and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an exponential decrease, while your x-values are discrete. You could log-transform your y-values and jitter your x-values (adding random numbers of +/- 0.2 or something of this order of magnitude) and then recheck the correlation.